# Laravel - Good practice to put query in custom request?

Tags: laravel

I use a custom query, and I add a custom rule to it too, and I wanted to know if putting eloquent queries in the rule is a "good practice"?

For me it's pretty dirty, but I don't really see how else to do it, and I haven't found any answers...
I have to make in the rule, parameters...

Edit (add code)

```html
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Model\Laravel\Api;
use App\Model\Laravel\Package;
use App\Model\Laravel\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ApiMax implements Rule
{
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @param $user
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $maxApi = $this->getPackageInfo($this->user)->max_api - $this->sumApis($this->user);

        if($value > $maxApi)
            return false;

        return true;

    }

    public function getPackageInfo(User $user)
    {
        return Package::where('id', $user->getPackageId())->first();
    }

    public function sumApis(User $user) {
        return Api::where('user_id', $user->getId())->count();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'You have reached the maximum number of apis with your current offer.';
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your tips

Comment: Why not use a service class?

Comment: @user3532758 Do you have a link to the documentation? I'm not sure I know what you're talking about

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_layer_pattern

Comment: is it possible you can show an example of what you are currently doing?

Comment: @lagbox i put my code in the post

Comment: @OMiShah I have a form to create an API, with a number of uses, and this one should not be exceeded. So I have a custom rule, which allows to check if this number is not exceeded.
And I want to know if putting the requests in the custom rule is good or not, apparently not, and from what I'm told, doing a separate service would be more like

Comment: Pattern discussions are always subjective. Introducing a new pattern could be costly depending on how far your project has proceeded. Getting back to your original question; Api and Package both seems to have a relationship with User. So to cure your unease, I would say  you could have an attribute (getMaxApiAttribute) in the User model. You can do the calculation once the relations have loaded. Then in the Rule class, you would just do `return ! $value > $this->user->maxApi;`

Comment: @user3532758 Ok I see, it's true that it's even better and simpler. So if I understand correctly, I do all the logic in the model, to make them reusable methods, and I just call them in the relationship. Thank you for your help